# Disable paging in ViewPager when a ImageView is zoomed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have used `ViewPager` for image sliding and I need to view the images with zoom option ,the image gets zoomed but the paging interrupts while zooming the image.Have tried `onTouchEvent()` and `OnInterceptTouchEvent()`.Disabling and Enabling `ViewPager` results in Force close.

Comment: To disable scrolling you have to use custom ViewPager class.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `ViewPager` and override `canScroll()`. You will be passed the widget over which the touch events were detected, and you can return `true` if you want the scroll event to passed to that widget or `false` if you want the `ViewPager` to use that scroll amount. In your case, you would employ your own custom logic when you are zoomed and simply chain to the superclasss when you are not zoomed.

Comment: Since I see a lot of questions coming up regrading this ViewPager-zoom combo, I'm surprised that there isn't a solid library out there that handles it, or is there?
I saw this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/mygxOpYwcKo
But only bottom two projects use Viewpager and both have either the problem described here or stability issues.
Anyway, do you Mark, or any of you guys know of an implementation combining ViewPager and zoom successfully? thanks

Comment: @Rob: Considering that the `ViewPager` subclass is a dozen or so lines of code, a library would seem excessive. Worse, the library would not know *a priori* what needs to be zoomed, and so I don't even know how you would implement such a library.

Answer (score 2):

I know this questions is old but for somebody else looking for an answer [Mike Ortiz TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) works out of the box, (you may need to switch to the dev branch)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem once and I did the following to solve this.I used a custom ViewPager class.

**CustomViewPager .java**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.isPagingEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

and to disable scrolling use the following snippet,

```
CustomViewPager pager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

If you need more info then you can ask. Hope it helps.

Comment: The code works but when I use that I lost the swipe in the wiewpager. thanks!

Comment: @benoffi7: This piece of code is to disable and enable paging.You can set it through `pager.setPagingEnabled(boolean);`

Comment: thanks! but when I activate for swipe and when desactivate for zoom?

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the following way, it will disable paging when the user zooms, but when he hits the edge of the zoomed imageview it will properly page onto the next / previous image.

```
 @Override 
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if(handleTouch(ev)) {
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override 
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if(handleTouch(ev) && !areCommentsOpen()) {
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private boolean handleTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (prevX != -666 && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if(ev.getX() <= prevX) {
                    isGoingLeft=false;
                }
                else {
                    isGoingLeft=true;
                }
            }
            else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                return true;
            }

            ZoomableImageView imageView = getImageView();
            if(imageView == null) {
                return true;
            }
            prevX=ev.getX();
            if(imageView.getZoomLevel() <= 1f) {
                return true;
            }

            else if(imageView.isBoundedLeft()) {
                if(isTransitioning) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (isGoingLeft) {
                    isTransitioning = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (imageView.isBoundedRight()) {
                if(isTransitioning) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (!isGoingLeft) {
                    isTransitioning = true;
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else {
                isTransitioning = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

private ZoomableImageView getImageView() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            ZoomableImageView imageView = (ZoomableImageView) (getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.single_image_view));
            if(imageView.getPosition() == getCurrentItem()) {
                return imageView;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setTransitioning(boolean trans) {
        this.isTransitioning = trans;
    }

    public void setGoingLeft(boolean left) {
        this.isGoingLeft = left;
    }
```

Comment: This is code that's inside a custom viewpager class. So you'd have

class MyPager extends ViewPager {
     //Code above
}

and in your xml you'd have

<com.your.package.path.MyPager />